# Converting Python to Scala-Spark

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, lda

I have a Python code that i want to convert it to Scala-Spark , my algorithm is an extension of LDA(Latent Dirichlet Allocation) because of this algorithm has a sampling process which is very time consuming when the data size is very big, and i know there is an implemented version of LDA in SparkMlib but i want to code my algorithm separately and adding some improvement on it, here is my code:

```
    def init_est(self):

        self.nd = [0 for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.ndl = [[0 for y in xrange(self.sentinum)] for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.ndlz = [[[0 for z in xrange(self.K)] for y in xrange(self.sentinum)] for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.nlzw = [[[0 for z in xrange(self.dset.V)] for y in xrange(self.K)] for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.nlz = [[0 for y in xrange(self.K)] for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.p = [[0.0 for y in xrange(self.K)] for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]

        self.Z = [ [] for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.L = [ [] for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]

        self.pi_dl = [[0 for y in xrange(self.sentinum)]for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.theta_dlz= [[[0 for z in xrange(self.K)]for y in xrange(self.sentinum)]for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.phi_lzw = [[[0 for z in xrange(self.dset.V)]for y in xrange(self.K)]for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.alpha_lz = [[0 for y in xrange(self.K)]for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.alphaSum_l = [0 for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.beta_lzw = [[[0 for z in xrange(self.dset.V)]for y in xrange(self.K)]for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.betaSum_lz = [[0 for y in xrange(self.K)]for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.lambda_lw = [[0 for y in xrange(self.dset.V)]for x in xrange(self.sentinum)]
        self.gama_dl = [[0 for y in xrange(self.sentinum)]for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]
        self.gamaSum_d = [0 for x in xrange(self.dset.M)]



        for x in xrange(self.dset.M):
            self.Z[x] = [0 for y in xrange(self.dset.docs[x].length)]
            self.L[x] = [0 for y in xrange(self.dset.docs[x].length)]

            for y in xrange(self.dset.docs[x].length):
                topic = random.randint(0, self.K-1)
                self.Z[x][y] = topic

                sentiment = random.randint(0,self.sentinum-1)
                for i in xrange(len(self.sdset.sentiLex)):
                   if (self.dset.id2word[self.dset.docs[x].words[y]]) == self.sdset.sentiLex[i][0]:
                      sentiment = self.sdset.sentiLex[i][1]

                #print sentiment
                self.L[x][y] = sentiment

                self.nd[x] +=1
                self.ndl[x][sentiment] +=1
                self.ndlz[x][sentiment][topic] +=1
                self.nlzw[sentiment][topic][self.dset.docs[x].words[y]] +=1
                self.nlz[sentiment][topic] +=1


    def estimate(self):
        print 'Sampling %d iterations!' % self.iter_num
        for x in xrange(self.iter_num):
            print 'Iteration %d ...' % (x+1)
            for i in xrange(len(self.dset.docs)):
                for j in xrange(self.dset.docs[i].length):
                    lst = self.sampling(i, j)
                    sentiment = lst[0]
                    topic = lst[1]

                    self.Z[i][j] = topic
                    self.L[i][j] = sentiment
            if (self.updateParaStep > 0 ) & (x % self.updateParaStep == 0):
                self.updateParameters()
            if (self.savestep > 0) & (x % self.savestep == 0):
                if (x == self.iter_num):
                    break
                print 'Saving the model at iteration...'
                self.compute_theta()
                self.compute_phi()
                self.compute_Pi()
                self.save_model()      

    def sampling(self, i, j):
        sentiment = self.L[i][j]
        topic = self.Z[i][j]
        wid = self.dset.docs[i].words[j]

        self.nd[i] -=1
        self.ndl[i][sentiment] -=1
        self.ndlz[i][sentiment][topic] -=1
        self.nlzw[sentiment][topic][wid] -=1
        self.nlz[sentiment][topic] -=1


        for l in xrange(self.sentinum):
            for k in xrange(self.K):
                self.p[l][k] = (self.nlzw[l][k][wid] + self.beta_lzw[l][k][wid])/(self.nlz[l][k] + self.betaSum_lz[l][k]) * \
                            (self.ndlz[i][l][k] + self.alpha_lz[l][k])/(self.ndl[i][l] + self.alphaSum_l[l]) * \
                            (self.ndl[i][l] + self.gama_dl[i][l])/(self.nd[i] + self.gamaSum_d[i])

        for l in xrange(self.sentinum):
            for k in xrange(self.K):
                if k==0:
                    if l==0:
                        continue
                    else:
                        self.p[l][k] = self.p[l][k] + self.p[l-1][self.K-1]
                else:
                    self.p[l][k] = self.p[l][k] + self.p[l][k-1]
        flag= False
        u = random.uniform(0, self.p[self.sentinum-1][self.K-1])
        for sentiment in xrange(self.sentinum):
            for topic in xrange(self.K):
                if self.p[sentiment][topic]>u:
                    flag = True
                    break
            if flag == True:
                break

        self.nd[i] +=1
        self.ndl[i][sentiment] +=1
        self.ndlz[i][sentiment][topic] +=1
        self.nlzw[sentiment][topic][wid] +=1
        self.nlz[sentiment][topic] +=1
        z=[sentiment,topic]
        return z

    def compute_theta(self):
        for m in xrange(self.dset.M):
            for l in xrange(self.sentinum):
                for z in xrange(self.K):
                    self.theta_dlz[m][l][z] = (self.ndlz[m][l][z] + self.alpha_lz[l][z]) \
                                       /(self.ndl[m][l] + self.alphaSum_l[l])

    def compute_phi(self):

        for l in xrange(self.sentinum):
            for z in xrange(self.K):
                for r in xrange(self.dset.V):
                    self.phi_lzw[l][z][r] = (self.nlzw[l][z][r]+ self.beta_lzw[l][z][r])\
                                            /(self.nlz[l][z] + self.betaSum_lz[l][z])

    def compute_Pi(self):
        for m in xrange(self.dset.M):
            for l in xrange(self.sentinum):
                self.pi_dl[m][l] = (self.ndl[m][l]+self.gama_dl[m][l])\
                                   /(self.nd[m]+self.gamaSum_d[m])

def readtrnfile():
    print 'Reading train data...'
    with open(trnfile, 'r') as f:
        docs = f.readlines()

    dset = Dataset()
    items_idx = 0
    for line in docs:
        if line not in [""," ","\n"] :
            tmp = line.strip().split()
            # Generate a document object
            doc = Document()
            for item in tmp:
                if dset.word2id.has_key(item):
                    doc.words.append(dset.word2id[item])
                else:
                    dset.word2id[item] = items_idx
                    dset.id2word[items_idx] = item
                    doc.words.append(items_idx)
                    items_idx += 1
            doc.length = len(tmp)
            dset.docs.append(doc)
        else:
            pass

    dset.M = len(dset.docs)
    dset.V = len(dset.word2id)
    print 'There are %d documents' % dset.M
    print 'There are %d items' % dset.V
    print 'Saving wordmap file...'
    dset.writewordmap()
    return dset


def readsentifile():

    print 'Reading sentimen data...'
    with open(sentifile, 'r') as s:
        senti = s.readlines()
    SL=[]
    sdset = SDataset()

    for line in senti:
        if line != "":
            tmp = line.strip().split()
            sdoc = SDocument()

            golabi=tmp[0]
            hasan=[tmp[1],tmp[2],tmp[3]]
            mval = max(hasan)
            midx = hasan.index(mval)

            s=[golabi,midx,mval]
            sdset.sentiLex.append(s)

        else:
            pass

    sdoc.length = len(sdset.sentiLex)
    return sdset

def lda():
    dset = readtrnfile()
    sdset = readsentifile()
    model = Model(dset,sdset)
    model.init_est()
    model.estimate()

if __name__=='__main__':
    lda()
```

i have some problem with implementing 3D matrices in scala and for loop in every RDD , for example i want to partition my data on different processor and every processor has own sampling (for loop) process, after sampling some global variables must be updated , here for me simplicity and Understandability of code is more important than optimization and high reducing time , Mlib implementation is based on Graphx and is very difficult to understand.

is there any solution for this?

Comment: You will probably get answers if you can more clearly state what you are looking for: Do you really only want to know if this can be solved with the help of Spark? (The answer is "yes".) Are you looking for someone to convert the Python code for you? (This is not the place to ask for that.) Do you have a specific question about the implementation in MLlib?

Comment: As you must be aware of this is quite a long code. I don't think anyone should feel interested in doing a code-translation for you.Also, this question violates many of the SO community guidelines. Read this - [ask]